# Keras Model fit throws shape mismatch error

Tags: tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, neural-network, nlp

I am building a Siamese network using Keras(TensorFlow) where the target is a binary column, i.e., match or mismatch(1 or 0). But the model fit method throws an error saying that the `y_pred is not compatible with the y_true shape`. I am using the `binary_crossentropy` loss function.

Here is the error I see:

[image]

Here is the code I am using:

```
model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer=optimizer, metrics=[tf.keras.metrics.Recall()])
history = model.fit([X_train_entity_1.todense(),X_train_entity_2.todense()],np.array(y_train),
                    epochs=2, 
                    batch_size=32,
                    verbose=2,
                    shuffle=True)
```

My Input data shapes are as follows:

```
Inputs:
X_train_entity_1.shape is (700,2822)
X_train_entity_2.shape is (700,2822)

Target:
y_train.shape is (700,1)
```

In the error it throws, `y_pred` is the variable which was created internally. What is `y_pred` dimension is 2822 when I am having a binary target. And 2822 dimension actually matches the input size, but how do I understand this?

Here is the model I created:

```
in_layers = []
out_layers = []
for i in range(2):
  input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
  embedding_layer = Embedding(embed_input_size+1, embed_output_size)(input_layer)
  lstm_layer_1 = Bidirectional(LSTM(1024, return_sequences=True,recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(embedding_layer)
  lstm_layer_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(512, return_sequences=True,recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(lstm_layer_1)

  in_layers.append(input_layer)
  out_layers.append(lstm_layer_2)

merge = concatenate(out_layers)
dense1 = Dense(256, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal', name='data_embed')(merge)
drp1 = Dropout(0.4)(dense1)
btch_norm1 = BatchNormalization()(drp1)
dense2 = Dense(32, activation='relu', kernel_initializer='he_normal')(btch_norm1)
drp2 = Dropout(0.4)(dense2)
btch_norm2 = BatchNormalization()(drp2)
output = Dense(1, activation='sigmoid')(btch_norm2)
model = Model(inputs=in_layers, outputs=output)
model.summary()
```

Since my data is very sparse, I used **todense**. And there the type is as follows:

```
type(X_train_entity_1) is scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
type(X_train_entity_1.todense()) is numpy.matrix
type(X_train_entity_2) is scipy.sparse.csr.csr_matrix
type(X_train_entity_2.todense()) is numpy.matrix
```

Summary of last few layers as follows:
[image]

Comment: Can you update your question with how the model was defined? Also what is the dtype of `X_train_entity_1.todense()` and `X_train_entity_2.todense()`?

Comment: @Djinn Added info as you suggested

Comment: Try to add a `Flatten` layer before your first `dense` layer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mismatched shape in the `Input` layer. The input shape needs to match the shape of a single element passed as `x`, or `dataset.shape[1:]`. So since your dataset size is `(700,2822)`, that is 700 samples of size 2822. So your input shape should be 2822.

Change:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(1,))
```

To:

```
input_layer = Input(shape=(2822,))
```

Comment: Great catch, I was overseeing this. But even after changing this, I still see the same error.

Comment: The last dense layer shape is (None, 2822, 1). What does this mean? I am expecting the binary output but what is this 2822 mean?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set `return_sequences` in the `lstm_layer_2` to `False`:

```
lstm_layer_2 = Bidirectional(LSTM(512, return_sequences=False, recurrent_dropout=0.2, dropout=0.2))(lstm_layer_1)
```

Otherwise, you will still have the timesteps of your input. That is why you have the shape `(None, 2822, 1)`. You can also add a `Flatten` layer prior to your output layer, but I would recommend setting `return_sequences=False`.

Note that a `Dense` [layer](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Dense) computes the dot product between the inputs and the kernel along the last axis of the inputs.